# Is this possible when Secure Embeding a Power BI report into an html page?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Looking to Secure Embed a bunch of reports into a html webpage/portal.

Does anyone know if it is possible to completely remove/hide the filter pane on the right as well as the tab bar along the bottom? (the bits highlighted below).

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in PBI service also. Follow the Below steps:

1. Open the report in Edit mode. Expand the filters pane. You can see hide/view icon and select it to hide.

[image: Filter pane]

2. Right click on the Page name and you can see `Hide Page` Select it.

[image: Hide page]

3. Save Your report and Go to File and then from Embed get your iframe link.
4. When you paste iframe in your HTML you can see that Filter Pane and Pages below are hidden

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The filter pane has been successfully hidden. However after hiding all the pages except the first one I still see one page tab when I paste iframe into HTML.  Is there a setting Ive missed somewhere in Power BI desktop or Power BI service?

Comment: When Embedding report in a sharepoint online, you can hide the navigation pane. In PBI service, I am able to hide the page pane in service, but when embedding using iframe, pane is back. Unable to figure out workaround for this

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

At the time of embedding report, Update the embedConfig settings like below.
Or use Api 'updateSettings` to update the settings after you embedded the report.

```
// The new settings that you want to apply to the report.
const newSettings = {
    panes: {
        filters: {
            visible: false,
          },

          pageNavigation: {
                visible: false
            },
    }
};
// Update the settings by passing in the new settings you have configured.
try {
    await report.updateSettings(newSettings);
}
catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings#panes
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/update-settings

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  Am I right in assuming your example applies to "Power BI Embedded Analtics" only.  As all Im actually doing is generating an embed code via PBI Service and then pasting it into an html page.  For example,  <html>
<head></head>
<body>  <iframe title="Report _v01.01" width="1004" height="740" src="h@@ps://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZZ....DI2ZSIsImMiOjh9&pageName=ReportSection" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>  
</body>
</html>

Comment: Try the below answer and Hope it works :)